# How to interface Python with Qlikview for data visualization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tableau-api, qlikview

I am using Scikit-Learn and Pandas libraries of Python for Data Analysis. 
How to interface Python with data visualization tools such as Qlikview?

Comment: You are asking more than one question. Please separate this into several questions instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no straightforward route to calling Python from QlikView. I have used this:

1. Create a Python program that outputs CSV (or any file format that QlikView can read)
2. Invoke your Python program from the QlikView script: `EXEC python3 my_program.py > my_output.csv`
3. Read the output into QlikView: `LOAD * FROM my_output.csv (...)`

Note that the `EXEC` command requires the privilege "Can Execute External Programs" on the Settings tab of the script editor.

Comment: Hi, I would like to implement something like this, but I would need some example. I try to save file inside python file, but it doesn't work... I wrote this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993334/execute-python-script-in-qlik-sense-load-script. Could you put example what is in my_program.py so that you can put output to py_output.csv.... thanks

Comment: @MarkoZadravec The example above expects that the Python program writes to the standard output (`sys.stdout`). So you would have in your program: `import sys; sys.stdout.write(my_data)`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.  I'm trying to find documentation for doing this and haven't found much.  I'm new to both Python and Qlik.  I want to send my simple linear regression to Qlik.  I'm not sure what to put into a file for Qlik to read.  My regressor and predictor or can I send the visualization?

Comment: @DataGirl: You would let Python crunch the numbers and put the results in the CSV file – textual labels for the various data points and the numeric data itself, probably two to four columns depending on the complexity. Then read the file into QlikView and create your visualisations there.

Comment: Thank you, @Waldo.  I'm definitely going to try that.  But, what if I want the end user to be able to make selections and have the regression populate when those selections have been made?

Comment: @DataGirl: I'm afraid that’s not possible. QlikView’s first nature is to load the data beforehand and then let the user play with the dataset, but not alter it.

Answer (score 2):

This link shows you how to integrate Qlikview and Python https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-14011

Comment: Link-only answers lose their value when the links break, please edit this answer to improve it. For guidance please see [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)