# Execute python script in Qlik Sense load script

Tags: python, qliksense

I am trying to run python script inside my load script in Qlik Sense app.

I know that I need to put `OverrideScriptSecurity=1` in `Settings.ini`

I put

```
Execute py lib://python/getSolution.py 100 'bla'; // 100 and 'bla' are parameters
```

and I get no error in qlik sense, but script is not executed (I think) because inside the script I have

```
f = open("file.xml", "wb")
f.write(xml)
f.close
```

and file is not saved.

If I run script from terminal, then script is properly executed.

What could go wrong?

By the way, my full path to python interpreter is

```
C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
```

### EDIT :

Even if I add this

```
Set vPythonPath = "C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";
Set vPythonFile = "C:\Users\Marko Z\Documents\Qlik\Sense\....\getSolution.py";

Execute $(vPythonPath) $(vPythonFile);
```

I get the same behaviour. No error, but not working,...
I even see that if I change path (incorrect path) it give me an error, but incorrect file it doesn't give me an error.... (but I am sure it is the right file path...)

My python code is

```
xml = "Marko"
xml = xml.encode('utf-8')
f = open("C:\\Users\\Marko Z\\Test.xml", "wb")
f.write(xml)
f.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out what was wrong. 
For all others that would have similar problems:

Problem is in space in path. 
If I move my script in c:\Windows\getSolution.py it work. I also need to change the python path to c:\Windows\py.exe

so end script looks like:

```
Execute c:\Windows\py.exe c:\Windows\getSolution.py 100 'bla';
```

But I still need to figure how to work with space in path...

Comment: Try putting double quotes around the paths: `Execute "$(vPythonPath)" "$(vPythonFile)";`. I'm not super familiar with Qlik Sense so this is just a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. With exactly the same python file and QS script the result file is generated correctly.

The content of my `settings.ini`.

```
[Settings 7]
StandardReload=0
OverrideScriptSecurity=1
```

**According to Qlik's documentation there should be an empty line at the end** (point 4 from the [lists](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Execute.htm))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the below to work in qlik sense:

```
set vPyExe = C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe;
set vPyScript = D:\...\PythonScript.py; 

Execute
"$(vPyExe)" "$(vSource)"
;
```